# many to many relationship relational db

Tags: mysql, database

I know technically mysql doesn't support many to many. We should create a bridge table. But in my case I still confused about that.

how 2 tables (or more) look like when many users can have many friends? think of it like social network app.

```
user
=====
id
name

friend
=====
id
name
```

I'm confused and don't know how to link them, because in a friend table an id can be also a users' id.

Answer (score 2):

Its best practicate to make that 3rd "mapping" table.

```
user
=====
id
name

m2m_user_friend
=====
user_id
friend_user_id
```

Both user_id and user_friend_id are foreign keys to that user table.

This allows most efficient querys like "Give me all friends of person id=17" and also, if friend-connections are one-directional (e.g. friendship requests), you can do things the other way around "show me people that are/want to be friends to id=17".

Social networks will use something called a graph database, most likely. Relational databases are great - unless you need to scale up. It gets though at some point to split your data on 10,000s of machines with tradional databases like MySQL.

Comment: This is good, but you how do you check if `friend_user_id` has `user_id` as their friend? You would need to have two datasets like `1,2` and `2,1` to build that. So it makes sense to introduce some business rules like "friendship relations are always omnidirectional" and "the `user_id` is always the lower integer and the `friend_user_id` is always the higher integer".

Comment: Actually you dont need to.
If you want to find all friendship relations of one id you can do so my setting your WHERE clause to catch both:
SELECT * from m2m_user_friend WHERE user_id = 17 OR friend_user_id = 17

Comment: Well, true, though that is not efficient. On the other hand, if you INSERT a new relation, you always need to check both to make sure you do not have them. If you however define that the lower id always comes first, you do not need to do the check in both directions before inserting a new line. You can just rely on the uniqueness of the primary key after putting the lower id first either in your app or as a stored procedure.

Comment: You can do so, whether its really so much performant.. doubt it. CPU Cycles are light-cost, memory access to cachelines is costly. But it will fetch both columns in one cache-line anyways in 97% of the cases. Such optimizations make it harder for other developers, though - if they'd have to change something on your project later one and didn't know about the lower_id stuff. I'd atleast give the column a name like lower_user_id. However, how do you do your SELECT then ? There will be 2 parts for each user: one where he is higher ID, one where he is lower. I think you missed that so far.

Answer (score 0):

The question is whether the relationship is necessarily symmetric, i.e. if Alice is Bob's friend implies that Bob is also Alice's friend.

In general this is not true and then you need instead of your table friend a table like this:

```
friends
======
user_id
friend_id
```

where both user_id and friend_id point to the table user (i.e. they are the foreign key constraints).

If the relationship is symmetric, I think that the above approach is still working and you can either always insert (or delete) two records, or you always need to check two columns.